# Views : SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found (concerning a Custom Value Table)

Tags: civievent, custom-fields, drupal-views

I want to create a View based upon civi_participants, including Participant Custom Fields.

I can Add the custom fields, but I get the following message :

*SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'bapaparoisse_drup_275.dr_civicrm_value_infos_parents_participants_11' doesn't exist*

... and the displayed view is empty.

(Running Civi 4.7.16 / Drupal 7.54 / Views 3.16)

Comment: Have you added the table aliases as described [here](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Views3+Integration)?

Comment: Are you using same database for drupal and civicrm or separate database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error usually means .... "Drupal doesn't know the table exists" ... which either means

1/ you have your civicrm tables in a different database and need to update the list of tables that you entered in settings.php so that drupal can connect to it

2/ the fields have been created, but no data has been stored yet (i may be wrong but i think the table for the data is created the first time a record is saved that contains data that needs storing in the table)

Comment: I actually forgot to update my settings.php file after adding a new custom data set. Everything is running OK now. Thank you all.